# Conditional filtering using dbplyr in Shiny

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, dbplyr

I am working on a business problem where I would like to filter data from a database in a shiny app based on user-supplied input from a list.

Here is the snippet of what works only after collecting the data from a database, which is computationally expensive.

```
reactive({
my_database_data %>%
collect() %>%
filter(
      if (!!input$list != 'All')
        (branch == !!input$list
        ) else TRUE)
})
```

I would like to achieve the same but doing so straight from the database.

```
reactive({
my_database_data %>%
filter(
      if (!!input$list != 'All')
        (branch == !!input$list
        ) else TRUE)
})
```

Not too sure of the if-else statement above.

Comment: It's unclear what the issue you're having is. Does the code work with the former (with `collect()`), but not with the latter? I guess there are two possible explanations:

1. Somehow the `filter` doesn't work with the same way with the remote source.
2. Something in the code requires local data (in which case, adding `collect()` after `filter()` might get it to work).

Comment: The code where I `collect()` first works. But I do not want to collect before I run the summary functions.

Comment: I understand the desire not to `collect()`. But does the code work if you flip the order of `filter()` and `collect()`? (Using `collect(n = 100)` or something might work *for diagnosis purposes* if the `collect()` is very costly.) If it doesn't work, then it suggests that the `filter()` is not getting translated to SQL in the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution to the problem.

```
reactive({
  # If 'All' not selected, filter
  if (input$list != 'All') {
    
    filter(my_database_data, branch == !!input$list)
    
  } else {
    
    my_database_data
    
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being sure what `input$list` contains, providing an exact solution is difficult. Drawing partly on @AaronSimumba's answer and partly on @IanGow's comments I would suggest something like the following:

```r
reactive({

if(input$list == 'All'){
  result = my_database_data %>%
    collect()
} else {
  result = my_database_data %>%
    filter(branch == !!input$list) %>%
    collect()

})
```

This means that if a filter is specified then the filter will be applied before the data is drawn into R. I am not sure there is any alternative to `collect`ing the data into R before using it in the app. This depends on how you are using the data after filtering.

Comment: I was able to solve this with the answer I have provided. I needed the query to provide the lazy data frame.