# Conditional filter of dbplyr query in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dbplyr

I'm working on a Shiny application that queries a database using `dbplyr` but I'm struggling to implement my usual `dplyr` approach for conditional filters using the proper syntax. It seems like the underlying issue is that `dbplyr` does not allow you to evaluate an externally-supplied vector, so `is.null` fails when the user supplies a vector of potential options.

```
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `mtcars`
WHERE (CASE WHEN (((4.0, 6.0) IS NULL)) THEN 1 WHEN (`cyl` IN (4.0, 6.0)) THEN 1 END)
```

Ultimately, there will be many parameters to evaluate so I don't want to simply put the whole query in an if/else statement [as has been suggested in similar SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68253842/conditional-filtering-using-dbplyr-in-shiny). Any suggestions for how to best implement conditional filters in a Shiny application built on `dbplyr`?

```
# load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)

# create database and dataframe
mtcars_db <- tbl_memdb(mtcars)
mtcars_df <- collect(mtcars_db)

# parameterized filter function
filter_function <- function(data, user_selection) {
  {{data}} |>
    filter(
      case_when(
        is.null({{user_selection}}) ~ TRUE,
        cyl %in% {{user_selection}} ~ TRUE
      )
    )
}

# save vector of user selections
cylinders <- c(4, 6)

# works with dataframes
filter_function(mtcars_df, NULL) # works
filter_function(mtcars_df, cylinders) # works
filter_function(mtcars_db, NULL) # works
filter_function(mtcars_db, cylinders) # fails

# show query of failing version
filter_function(mtcars_db, cylinders) |>
  show_query()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically recommend the approach by @langtang, but with multiple conditions it is clear this can become impractical.

The cause of the problem is that SQL does not have a way to test whether an entire list (e.g. `(4.0, 6.0)`) is null. Hence, one solution is to test only the first value of the list:

```r
filter_function <- function(data, user_selection) {
  data %>%
    filter(
      cyl %in% user_selection | is.null(local(user_selection[1]))
      )
}
```

I have used OR (`|`) instead of `case_when` and removed the `{{ }}` as it works without. But this is only a style choice.

The key part of this solution is `local`, which forces evaluation of its contents prior to translation. If we do not include `local` then dbplyr is trying to translate something like `(4.0, 6.0)[1]` (which it can not do). But when we use `local`, dbplyr just have to translate `4` (which is trivial).

This makes use of the R behavior that `NULL[1]` is also `NULL`.

We have to assume that `user_selection` never has `NULL` as a first value. This should generally be the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you return `data` when `is.null(user_selection)`, then your filter function works in all four of your use cases:

```
filter_function <- function(data, user_selection) {
  if(is.null(user_selection)) return(data)
  filter(data, case_when(cyl %in% {{user_selection}} ~ TRUE))
}
```